# Nx mono repo with NestJs & angularJs not reloading in container

Tags: docker, nrwl-nx

I have created a NX monorepo with angular and nestJS apps and tried very hard to make the reload work inside containers but to no avail. Even though the directories are mounted correctly and I verified that changes in the host are being written inside the container but somehow the process is not picking them up.

I have created a standalone nestJS application and successfully made it work with the container.

Github repo: https://github.com/navdbaloch/dockerized-development-with-nx-monorepo-angular-nestjs

ENV: windows 10 with WSL2, Docker Desktop 4.2.0

Follow is the docker-compose.xml file

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  frontend:
    container_name: test-frontend
    hostname: poirot_frontend
    image: poirot_frontend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/fwa/Dockerfile.angular
      target: development
    ports:
      - 4200:4200
    networks:
      - poirot-network
    depends_on:
      - api
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src
      - /usr/src/node_modules
    command: npm run start:app
  api:
    container_name: test-api
    hostname: poirot_api
    image: poirot_api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/fwa-api/Dockerfile.api
      target: development
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src
      - /usr/src/node_modules
    ports:
      - 3333:3333
      - 9229:9229
    command: npm run start:api
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - poirot-network

networks:
  poirot-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile.angular

```
FROM node:14-alpine As development

WORKDIR /usr/src
COPY package*.json ./
RUN  npm install minimist && \
    npm install --only=development

COPY . .
RUN npm run build:app

#! this is the production image
FROM nginx:latest as production
COPY ./docker/angular.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=development /usr/src/dist/apps/fwa /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Dockerfile.api

```
FROM node:14-alpine As development

WORKDIR /usr/src

COPY package*.json ./

RUN  npm install minimist &&\
  npm install --only=development

COPY . .

RUN npm run build:api

#! this is the production image
FROM node:14-alpine as production

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN  npm install minimist typescript ts-node lodash reflect-metadata tslib rxjs @nestjs/platform-express @types/bcrypt && \
  npm install --only=production

COPY . .
COPY --from=development /usr/src/dist/apps/fwa-api ./dist
EXPOSE 3333
#! Migration runenr command: node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js migration-runner.ts
CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I was able to make it work after a lot of trial and error.

For angular application, changed server command from `npx nx serve` to `npx nx serve --host 0.0.0.0 --poll 2000`.

For the Api, add `"poll": 2000` option in `angular.json` at `projects.api.architect.build.options`

I have also updated [Github repo](https://github.com/navdbaloch/dockerized-development-with-nx-monorepo-angular-nestjs) for reference to anyone looking for the same solution.